# Queues with non-constant arrival rates

Tags: r, simulation, poisson-process, queueing

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simmer/index.html

I am interested in simulating some basic queues in R. However, I want to try to simulate queues that have "non-constant" arrival rates, i.e. the arrival rates are a function of time (e.g. instead of saying "50 people arrive every hour on average throughout the day" - we make the arrival rate a function that reflects more people coming through out certain times and fewer people coming at other times).

I did some research and came across the "simmer" package in R. This appears to be one of the main packages for queue simulation in R. However, I am not sure if this package can model "non constant arrivals".

Does anyone know if this is possible? Are there any ways to do this in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Our very own [Ben O'Neill](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/173082/ben) has written a package for simulating queues. I am not sufficiently familiar with the feature set, but I would consider looking at [O'Neill 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.07064).

Answer (score 0):

I will have to bow out of looking into the `R` constraint of this question, but for those willing to look at a `python` solution please continue reading.

> However, I want to try to simulate queues that have "non-constant" arrival rates, i.e. the arrival rates are a function of time (e.g. instead of saying "50 people arrive every hour on average throughout the day" - we make the arrival rate a function that reflects more people coming through out certain times and fewer people coming at other times).

We can do this with Ciw. In [How to Define Time and State Dependent Distributions](https://ciw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Guides/time_dependent.html) we are shown a Python class implementing a time-dependent distribution.

```py
class TimeDependentDist(ciw.dists.Distribution):

    def sample(self, t, ind=None):
        if t % 24 < 12.0:
            return 0.5
        if t % 24 < 14.0:
            return 0.25
        if t % 24 < 20.0:
            return 0.75
        return 1.5
```

This sampler has degenerate cases, and is nothing more than the following piecewise probability density function:

$$\text{pdf}(t) = \begin{cases} \delta \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) &  t\mod 24 < 12 \\ \delta \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) & t \mod 24 < 14 \\ \delta \left( \frac{3}{4} \right ) & t \mod 24 < 20 \\ \frac{3}{2} & \text{Otherwise} \end{cases}$$

where $\delta \left( \bullet \right)$ is the [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

So to run a G(t)/M/1 in Ciw, we can do the following:

```py
import ciw

ciw.seed(2018)

network = ciw.create_network(
    arrival_distributions=[TimeDependentDist()],
    service_distributions=[ciw.dists.Exponential(1)],
    number_of_servers=[1]
)

simulation = ciw.create_network(network)

simulation.simulate_until_max_time(356)

records = simulation.get_all_records()
```

Once you understand this example it should be possible to generalize to other samplers.